# MariaDB log_error system variable, configuration file difference between Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04

Tags: mysql, configuration, mariadb

**Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa)**

```
# dpkg -l | grep mariadb-server-10
ii  mariadb-server-10.3             1:10.3.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1        amd64        MariaDB database server binaries

# grep -E 'skip_log_error|syslog|log_error' /etc/mysql/ -R | grep -v '#'
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf:log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysqld_safe.cnf:skip_log_error
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysqld_safe.cnf:syslog

# tail -2 /var/log/mysql/error.log
2023-07-28  8:30:23 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.3.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Ubuntu 20.04
```

**Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)**

```
# dpkg -l | grep mariadb-server-10
ii  mariadb-server-10.6             1:10.6.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1

# grep -E 'skip_log_error|syslog|log_error' /etc/mysql/ -R | grep -v '#'
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysqld_safe.cnf:skip_log_error
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysqld_safe.cnf:syslog

# tail -2 /var/log/mysql/error.log
tail: cannot open '/var/log/mysql/error.log' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Up until Ubuntu 22.04, the MariaDB log was written to `/var/log/mysql/error.log`. Since the `log_error` system variable has apparently been removed in Ubuntu 22.04 from `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`, this isn't the case anymore.

- Why was `log_error` removed from the configuration file `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`?
- Why was the log file `/var/log/mysql/error.log` still created in Ubuntu 20.04, even though `skip_log_error` was used by default?

  - I assume this is due to the order in which the configuration files are processed, if so, where can I see this?

Side note
The log file did not exist before MariaDB was installed.

```
# ls /var/log/mysql/error.log
ls: cannot access '/var/log/mysql/error.log': No such file or directory
# dpkg -l | grep mariadb-server-10
# apt install mariadb-server
(...)
# dpkg -l | grep mariadb-server-10
ii  mariadb-server-10.3             1:10.3.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1        amd64        MariaDB database server binaries
# ls /var/log/mysql/error.log
/var/log/mysql/error.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `log_error` system variable has been removed by MariaDB here: https://salsa.debian.org/mariadb-team/mariadb-server/-/commit/bb8477778b72f047437b2a03a2bd38997e155f10#d3b22343b539ed028e5c8bf973b769b861541893_63_62

The reason why logging still worked in Ubuntu 20.04 even though `skip_log_error` was configured is due to the file order.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you didn't set log_error before in the past?

In mariadb select the variable to see the value:

```
select @@log_error
```

For as long as I can remember systemd being used, log_error has defauled to no value so the error log is written to STDOUT/STDERR so systemd can catch it.

You can still read the log data with journalctl:

```
journalctl -u mariadb.service
```

EDIT: looking at that file, it can be ignored:

```
$ cat /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysqld_safe.cnf
# NOTE: THIS FILE IS READ ONLY BY THE TRADITIONAL SYSV INIT SCRIPT, NOT SYSTEMD.
# MARIADB SYSTEMD DOES _NOT_ UTILIZE MYSQLD_SAFE NOR READ THIS FILE.
#
# For similar behavior, systemd users should create the following file:
# /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
#
# To achieve the same result as the default 50-mysqld_safe.cnf, please create
# /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
# with the following contents:
# [Service]
# User = mysql
# StandardOutput = syslog
# StandardError = syslog
# SyslogFacility = daemon
# SyslogLevel = err
# SyslogIdentifier = mysqld
#
# For more information, please read https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/systemd/
```

Comment: Yes, both servers are freshly installed, they were test environments with fresh OS and manual MariaDB installations.
No configurations were changed during, before or after testing.

Comment: Also, afaik, things like InnoDB corruption would not be logged in journalctl in this case.

Comment: All error messages are logged to the journalctl via stderr, including InnoDB errors.